# Can i check in app purchase on jailbreak

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, jailbreak

I am just worried that can i test in app purchase on the iphone which is jail broken
Please tell me i have used all weapons to use it in my device but every time the Productid is zero
please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a workaround here http://www.funkyspacemonkey.com/jailbroken-iphone-users-app-purchases

Comment: Yes i am getting the invalid ProductID .Posted some questions also but getting no success.

Comment: @RSS Do you have a wildcard in your appID?

Comment: I have followed all rules and following this tutorial

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: @RSS - But you're on a Jail broken phone - so there are some differences.