# In app purchase didReceiveResponse does not show my product

Tags: ios-simulator, in-app-purchase, storekit, iphone-3gs

By some mysterious reasons I got myself a jailbroken iPhone 3GS from a vendor whom I am finding difficult to track.
My task is to test out in app purchase functionality on it.
Currently it has iOS 5.0.1 with cydia installed.
[No, it does not have Appsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815165/can-i-check-in-app-purchase-on-jailbreak).

I am installing my build through testflightapp API which works without issues with my app so far.
However when I initiate in app purchase, I don't get anything in response.products so far.

I have added productIDs and all in itunes-connect already, checked twice that they are fine, since 48 hours.

I tried testing with iPhone simulator 5.1, but all I got was no values from storekit. I would love to hear if there is any workaround with simulator.

Comment: I double-checked everything on apple docs. Yet, no progress on this one. On itunes-connect, here are the status:

1) For my app: Waiting For Upload
2) For my in app purchase product: Waiting for Review
3) In app purchase product: Cleared for sale - Yes
4) Product ID requested: com.companyname.productname
5) App ID for provisioning profile with which app is built: com.companyname.appname
6) App ID used to create app on iTunes connect: same as above - com.companyname.appname

My testflightapp account is also updated with profile in 5) above, still no result. I see no reason why..but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around this finally - deleted my app from itunes connect, re-added it.
It complained about name being already used.
I changed the language of name. And it worked.

Maybe, my prior app setup was right, but I had something else messed up.
In between, I rejected my app. That maybe one of the reason behind this issue.

Lesson?
Don't developer reject your app.